# Using JOIN when reading from SQLite via ContentResolver

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I join two tables when using ContentResolver in android?
Right now I am able to access the USERS table this way:

```
    contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContentProviderDB.CONTENT_URI, DatabaseTables.USERS);
    selection = DatabaseColumns.USER_ID + " = " + String.valueOf(userId);
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, selection, null, null);
```

But how do I join with USER_PRODUCTS for example? As far as I can tell, the "query" method does not support JOIN operations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I join two tables when using ContentResolver in android?

You don't. Your `ContentProvider` needs to expose some virtual "table" that represents the `JOIN`.

This is reminiscent of a REST-style Web service. The client of such a service is limited to the specific things exposed by the service. The client cannot directly express a `JOIN` on such a Web service, except to the extent that the service itself has a prepared interface for doing such a `JOIN`.

Comment: So I should prepare a joined table in my SQLite beforehand?

Comment: @J.Kowalski: I do not know what "prepare a joined table" means in this context. When you wrote your `ContentProvider`, you implemented a `query()` method. Right now, that `query()` method examines the `Uri`, determines what table is tied to that query, and queries that table. For `JOIN`s, you extend the `query()` method to match other `Uri` values as representing the `JOIN`, and you run a query that `JOIN`s the tables as desired.

Answer (score 2):

In case you still wondering, there is example of custom content provider, which joins 2 table. Note the projection in `query`, you need to set aliase for '_id'. If you make projection just for '_id' you will get ambiguse columns exceptions, as there are 2 such columns, if you dont make any, you will not be able to use resulting cursor with loaders.

```
public class ContactsWithCategorisProvider extends ContentProvider {

  private MySQLiteHelper database;

  // used for the UriMacher
  private static String TABLE_NAME = buildTableName();
  private static String TABLE_ID = ContactsTable._ID;
  private static String AUTHORITY = "some_authority";

  private static final int ITEMS = 10;
  private static final int ITEM_ID = 20;
  private static final String BASE_PATH = "yourbase";
  private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
  public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + BASE_PATH);

  private static String buildTableName() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(ContactsTable.TABLE_NAME);
    sb.append(" LEFT OUTER JOIN ");
    sb.append(ContactsCategoriesTable.TABLE_NAME);
    sb.append(" ON(");
    sb.append(ContactsCategoriesTable.CONTACT_ID);
    sb.append(" = ");
    sb.append(ContactsTable.CONTACT_ID);
    sb.append(" AND ");
    sb.append(ContactsCategoriesTable.CURRENT_USER);
    sb.append(" = ");
    sb.append(ContactsTable.CURRENT_USER);
    sb.append(") ");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  static {
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, ITEMS);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", ITEM_ID);
  }

  @Override public boolean onCreate() {
    database = new MySQLiteHelper(getContext());
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
      String sortOrder) {

    // Uisng SQLiteQueryBuilder instead of query() method
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    // check if the caller has requested a column which does not exists
    //      checkColumns(projection);
    Log.e("check_uri", uri.toString());
    // Set the table
    queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
    if (projection == null || projection.length == 0) {
      projection = new String[] {
          ContactsTable.TABLE_NAME + "." + ContactsTable._ID + " AS " + ContactsTable._ID,
          ContactsTable.NAME, ContactsTable.NAME_SHORT, ContactsTable.NUMBER, ContactsTable.NOTE,
          ContactsTable.CATEGORIES, ContactsCategoriesTable.NAME, ContactsTable.CONTACT_ID
      };
    }
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (uriType) {
      case ITEMS:
        break;
      case ITEM_ID:
        queryBuilder.appendWhere(TABLE_ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =
        queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

    return cursor;
  }

  @Override public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
    long id;
    switch (uriType) {
      case ITEMS:
        id = sqlDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return Uri.parse(BASE_PATH + "/" + id);
  }

  public void insert(Uri uri, ArrayList<ContentValues> values) {

    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
    switch (uriType) {
      case ITEMS:
        for (ContentValues c : values) {
          sqlDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, c);
        }
        break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
  }

  @Override public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowsDeleted = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
      case ITEMS:
        rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
        break;
      case ITEM_ID:
        String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
          rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ID + "=" + id, null);
        } else {
          rowsDeleted =
              sqlDB.delete(TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ID + "=" + id + " and " + selection, selectionArgs);
        }
        break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsDeleted;
  }

  @Override
  public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowsUpdated = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
      case ITEMS:
        rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
        break;
      case ITEM_ID:
        String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
          rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(TABLE_NAME, values, TABLE_ID + "=" + id, null);
        } else {
          rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(TABLE_NAME, values, TABLE_ID + "=" + id + " and " + selection,
              selectionArgs);
        }
        break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsUpdated;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if I want to join multiple tables by passing a string parameter to check to join in contentprovider... can't get a good sample anywhwere.

Comment: @DilipPoudel dont really understand your problem, can you give more details

Comment: Its simple , I have six tables and I need to process join Query to get the rows from all six table with same name. (Name is unique column and same for all six table) And I am using Content Provider for my app.

Comment: @DilipPoudel create the View which is pululated via select statment from all your six table, than use your content provider to query that view. As view is always updated whenever tables content changes, you do no need manually update it.

Comment: @DilipPoudel you also can peek to google calendar sourcecode, there is an exceptional example of using using temptable populated from joins in content provider